# mu4e crashing when drag-and-dropping file attachment in mu4e:compose mode

Tags: mu4e

I am running Emacs 29.1 (9.0) on Mac OS Ventura 13.5 and have recently upgraded to mu4e 1.10.7.

Since after the upgrade, Emacs crashes whenever I try to drag-and-drop a file into mu4e:compose mode in order to attach it to an e-mail.

Actually, the behavior is slightly more weird. I can attach text files without Emacs crashing, if I have drag-and-dropped the file before to Emacs and opened it (e.g., in the scratch buffer), and then drag-and-drop it into the mu4e:compose buffer. In this case, I get the expected

<#part filename="/file.txt" disposition=attachment>
<#/part>

in the mu4e:compose buffer.

Also, if I drag-and-drop a file that I have opened before in another mu4e buffer (such as the headers view), then Emacs crashes.

Upon crashing, I get the error message "Emacs quit unexpectedly."

All this worked fine before the upgrade to mu4e 1.10.7.

Does anyone have similar problems, or any ideas where this could come from and how it could be fixed?